# How to handle "Property or field cannot be found on object in SpEL"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

How to handle `Property or field <foo> cannot be found on object of type <bar>` in SpEL ?
e.g. If data doesn't have placeId property on it then It shouldn't give me above error and return differentValue.

`"${@block?.value?.data?.placeId ?: 'differentValue'}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct. SpEL is just an another JVM language. It's not non-typed language like JavaScript. So, what is going to happen if your Java class doesn't have some property? Right: `Property or field <foo> cannot be found on object of type <bar>`.

Therefore a logic in the expression must not rely on some non-Java reflection logic.

You definitely need to have there something like `instanceof`, but you may live without casting to get access to existing properties.