# How to check for field existance in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

```
<nav th:if="${page} and ${page?.totalPages != null} and ${page?.totalPages > 1}"/>
```

What if the `page` object does not have a `getTotalPages()` method or `totalPages` field?

Then I get the following error:

```
    Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
       Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "page.totalPages != null"
    Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
       EL1008E: Property or field 'totalPages' cannot be found on object of type
       'org.springframework.data.domain.SliceImpl' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Question: how can I tell thymeleaf to validate if the property exists at all?

Comment: I think the answer is: What you are seeing is how it works, for the reasons given here: [How to handle "Property or field cannot be found on object in SpEL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52321764/12567365)

Comment: okay, while I don't get the difference between a field that is `null` in contrast to a missing field, obviously for thymeleaf it's not the same - which I thought.

Comment: I assume it's more about how Java handles these things, since Thymeleaf delegates invocation of the method to Java (using reflection, I assume). Your error is the error you get if you try to invoke a non-existent method (using reflection) with pure Java. Also, Thymeleaf does not have any `try-catch` syntax - which is what you would probably need, if you wanted to somehow handle the exception in your Thymeleaf template. (Someone with more knowledge about Thymeleaf internals can correct me where I may be wrong.)

Comment: @andrewJames You are right about Thymeleaf using reflection to access public properties and methods.

Comment: @membersound And that's why you get the message "maybe not public or not valid?" in your stacktrace : public access not found or method does not exists or invalid with more or less params (as an example). And they did not give deeper explanations in stacktrace because it is really easy and fast to check that kind of stuff as a developer.